# How to make an id stick when trying to leave a post comment

Tags: php, html, sticky

I'm having trouble on having my id stick when I'm trying to make a comment on a post on my site. So far when I click on the comment it has its id (ex. id=4), however, when I click on 'leave comment' the id doesn't stick and just says (id=) and not the number so I can't leave a comment because it doesn't know where to leave the comment.

I've tried defining a variable $comments = $_GET['id']; and putting it in the form action but that didn't seem to work. I've tried putting "?id= . $_GET['id']; in the form action as well, but that also didn't seem to work.

**I have put starts next to what I think is the important part of my code**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<!-- this includes the header and mysqli pages-->

<?php
include('includes/header.html');
include('includes/mysqli_connect.php');
?>

<head>

</head>
<body>
<!-- this styles the css for my form to make it look nice -->
<style type="text/css">
body{
    font-family: Arial, Gadget, sans-serif;
    background-color: #FFD9D9;
}
strong{
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
center{
    margin: auto;
}

</style>



<!-- have access to posting special characters and will trim unnecessary spaces-->
<?php
$userid = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_SESSION['user_id']));
$blogid = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_GET['id']));
$comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['comment']));
***$comments = $_GET['id'];***

#This adds in the comment based on their ID, email,fname,lname and date they made the comment
if (($title != NULL) && ($post != NULL)){
$query = "INSERT INTO comments (comid, userid, blogid, comment, comdate) VALUES (NULL, '$userid', '$blogid', '$comment', NOW());";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

#This displays an error if there was an error in making a comment
#EDIT: The "There was an error" never will display since my form validates if criteria was filled out or not, if it's not it makes the guest fill out that area
if ($result) {
    echo "<center><strong>Thank you, the comment has been added.</strong></center><br /><br />"; 
    $title = NULL;
    $title = NULL;

    }
else {
    echo "<strong>There was an error! </strong>" . mysqli_error($dbc);
    }
}



?>


<form action="<?php echo basename(__FILE__) . ***"?id=" . $comments;*** ?>" method="post">

<?php
if(($_POST['comment'] == NULL) && ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')){
    echo "<strong><center>Please fill in a comment!</center></strong><br />";
}
?>

<p><center><label><b>Leave comments here: </p></center></label></b>
<p align="center"><textarea name="comment" cols="40" rows="5">
<?php echo $_POST['comment'];
?>
</textarea>
</p>



<br />
<p align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>

<!--this includes the footer page-->
<?php
include('includes/footer.html');
?>
</body>
</html>
```

comments.php code:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>

<head>

</head>
<body>
<!-- this styles the css for my form to make it look nice -->
<style type="text/css">
body{
    font-family: Arial, Gadget, sans-serif;
    background-color: #FFD9D9;

}
strong{
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
center{
    border-left: .17em dashed;
    border-top: .17em solid;
    border-right: .17em dashed;
    border-bottom: .17em solid;
    padding-left:25px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    width: 1000px;
    background-color: #E1A0A0;
    border-color: black;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: left;

}
h3 {
text-align: center;
color: red; 
}

</style>
<!-- this includes the header and mysqli pages-->
<?php
include('includes/header.html');
include('includes/mysqli_connect.php');
?>


<?php
$blogid = $_GET['id'];
?>

<?php
$query = "SELECT blogid, title, post, DATE_FORMAT (postdate, '%M, %d, %Y') AS date, post FROM blogposts WHERE blogid=$blogid";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
?>

<!-- this will display the ID, fname, lname, email, comment, and date posted gathered from the MYSQL database-->
<?php
while ($rowb = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<center><h2>" . $rowb['title'] . "</h2>" . "<b>Posted On: </b>" . $rowb['date'] . "<br/>" . '<br/><a href="leavecomments.php?id=' . $row['blogid'] . '">Leave Post Comment</a>' . "\n";
      if($_SESSION['user_id'] == 3) {
            echo '| <a href="update.php?id=' . $row['blogid'] . '" >Update Blog Post</a> | <a href="' . basename(__FILE__) . '?id=' . $row['blogid'] . '" >Delete Blog Post</a>';
        }
        echo "</center>";
}
?>

<div align="center">
<h2>
Comments
</h2>
</div>

<?php
//define query
$q = "SELECT * FROM comments JOIN users USING (userid) WHERE $blogid";
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); //run query
?>

<!-- this will display the ID, fname, lname, email, comment, and date posted gathered from the MYSQL database-->
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<center><br/>" . "<b>Comment: </b>" . $row['comment'] . "<br /><br/>" . "<b>ID: </b>" . $row['comid'] . "<br />" . "<b>First Name: </b>" . $row['fname'] . "<br />" . "<b>Last Name: </b>" . $row['lname'] . "<br />" . "<b>Email: </b>" . $row['email'] . "<br />" . "<b>Posted At: </b>" . $row['comdate'] . "<br/></center>\n";

}
?>



<!--this includes the footer page-->
<?php
include('includes/footer.html');
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like the id to stick so I can put in a comment and it will show up on my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, its all ok, but you have bad prompt in your code:

```
<a href="leavecomments.php?id=' . $row['blogid'] . '" not use $row but $rowb
```

Comment: Where you define $title and $post?

Comment: Get variable from the url of the address you are calling: blog.php?id=4

Comment: I'm calling from comments.php and going to leavecomments.php

Comment: You must calling php file with parameter commnets.php?id=id_of_comment if not, your $_GET will by empty...

Comment: Could you show me what that'd look like? I don't completely understand what you're trying to say. Sorry for any inconveniences

Comment: Define your ID in url, see this and compare: https://seo-solution.cz/commnets.php?id=10 https://seo-solution.cz/commnets.php

if(!empty($_GET['id'])){
 //id from get is set
 echo "ID is: ".$_GET['id'];
}else {
 echo "ID is empty";
 //id from get isnt set
}

Comment: I should put that on comments.php code. can it put if(!empty($_GET['id'])){ //id from get is set echo "ID is: ".$_GET['id']; }else { echo "ID is empty"; //id from get isnt set } anywhere in the code? I don't have any form action or forms on the page

Comment: You have form on page comments.php and set his action with GET parameter id  but your prompt $_GET['id'] is empty. If you call your script like this http://www.example.com/comments.php?id=10 your action in form will by action="scriptname.php?id=10" and if you send this form your GET['id'] in script set to 10

Comment: I don't have any form fields on comments.php you can see my code in the question for comments.php

Comment: You set attribute action in your form with url and parameter id. Sou you need set this parameter with some id of your comment. Can you post here your url with form?

Comment: https://mpsippy.uwmsois.com/440%20final%20project/login/index.php is the url. Click view post comments to get to comments.php, click leave post comments to get to leavecomments.php. As you can see the id doesn't stick going from comments.php to leavecomments.php

Comment: Yep, its all ok, but you have bad prompt in your code: <a href="leavecomments.php?id=' . $row['blogid'] . '" not use $row but $rowb

Comment: yup, didn't notice that. Thanks a ton!